# How to get the string in xml attributes as lower cases in clojure

Tags: xml, clojure

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Transformation>
    <ColumnValidations>
        <Column ColumnName="Column1"/>
        <Column ColumnName="Column2" MinInclusive="100" MaxExclusive="10000"/>
        <Column ColumnName="GREGORIAN_DATE" IsDate="Yes" Format="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
    </ColumnValidations>
</Transformation>
```

Using `xml/parse` and `tree-seq`, it will generate something like `{:ColumnName "Column1"}`, is there is simple way to convert all the values into lower case in the map (which is also the attribute value)

```
xml-content (->> (xml/parse file)
                 (tree-seq :content :content))
```

Comment: Could you add what the code currently produces and what you want it to produce?

Comment: should just the values be lowercased, or the keys as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tree-sec is returning a sequence of maps. As one way to go about this is to then map a function over that sequence that calls .toLower on each value in each map:

```
 (->> (xml/parse file)
         (tree-seq :content :content)
         (map #(zipmap (keys %) (map clojure.string/lower-case (vals %)))))
```

Assuming all the values are strings. You may want to put an or in there if they are not

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar with the `fmap` function in `clojure.algo.generic.functor`, which maps over various functors:

> Applies function f to each item in the data structure s and returns a
>   structure of the same kind.

This means you can transform the elements in a data structure but unlike standard `map` (which can only return a lazy sequence), it will return a data structure of the same type as the one passed in.

So you can recursively `fmap` over the xml data structure, applying `clojure.string/lower-case` to any string you find:

```
(ns mynamespace
  (:require [clojure.xml :as xml]
            [clojure.algo.generic.functor :refer [fmap]]
            [clojure.string :as str])
  (:import [java.lang String]
           [java.util List Map]))

(defn lower-case-string-vals [m]
  (fmap (fn [v]
          (cond
           (isa? (type v) String) (str/lower-case v)
           (or (isa? (type v) Map)
               (isa? (type v) List)) (lower-case-string-vals v)
               :else v))
        m))

(lower-case-string-vals (xml/parse "thefile.xml"))
```

(The second part of the `cond` is a bit ugly: it would be nice to know if `v` is of a type for which the multimethod `fmap` has an implementation, but I'm not sure that's possible, except with a try-catch).